# Retrofit 2, GSON and custom deserializer

Tags: android, gson, deserialization, retrofit

I've been using Retrofit 2 with some POJO objects for a while now. It's a lovely library and works very well, but it's necessitating some horrendous and messy models that I want to get rid of.

I'll show you... I have the following JSON to peruse:

```
    {
    "things": [
        {
            "thing": {
                "id": 823,
                "created_at": "2016-02-09T22:55:07.153Z",
                "published_at": "2016-02-10T19:23:42.666Z",
                "downloads": 16073,
                "size": 10716291
            }
        },
    ],
    "count": 4,
    "links": {}
    }
```

Using the POJO Schema generator this creates unnecessary classes that make maintaining code hard to do.

This would create:

```
Things.java
    @SerializedName("things")
    @Expose
    public List<Things_> things = new ArrayList<>();
Things_.java
    @SerializedName("thing")
    @Expose
    private Thing__ thing;
Things__.java
    // Insert normal variables and getter/setters here
```

I've reduced that down a little as it's just for the idea. In my usage I have of course renamed these classes to make them more managable. But I figured there was a way of simply skipping over Thing and Thing_ and allowing me to just return a list of the actual model data (Thing__) and this two of those classes could be removed and "Thing__" could simple be "Thing".

I was right. Gson allows custom deserialization that lets me achieve this end. I threw together a quick Deserializer and used an appropriate TypeToken

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<ArrayList<Thing>>(){}.getType(), new AddonDeserializer())
            .create();

    List<Thing> model = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Thing>>(){}.getType());
```

Sure enough, passing this that exact Json above give me a List of Things that were usable.

Enter Retrofit 2! Having added the registerTypeAdapter() to my Retrofit 2 instance (via my gson instance) I now get an error message:

```
 Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

This is because, probably, my call is:

```
@Get("end/of/url/here/{slug}.json") 
Call<List<Thing>> getThings(@Path("slug") String slug);
```

My Json starts with an object ("things") which contains an array of "thing" objects. My deserializer had no issues with this:

```
public class ThingDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<Thing>> {
    @Override
    public List<Thing> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("things");

        ArrayList<Thing> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (JsonElement anArray : array) {
            list.add((Thing) context.deserialize(anArray.getAsJsonObject().get("thing").getAsJsonObject(), Thing.class));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Anyway, thanks for sticking with this very long question!

What do I need to do differently or how can I manipulate Retrofit to act the same as the Gson Deserializer I wrote? What I have works, but in the interests of learning something new and writing nicer and more maintainable code I want to figure this out. I could just resort to using ResponseBody callbacks and throwing the Json through my Deserializer but there has to be a better method.

Comment: I can't understand why you dont have a class, lets call it, ThingsResponse containing a list of Things, and the other two attributes, count and links. And use that pojo to get the retrofit answer from api call.

Comment: @JonathanAste I could. That's basically what I have now. But there's three classes for one model. Eventually I'm going to be parsing an XML file with slightly layouts into the same models. Would be extremely useful to slim these down a little. I'm just wondering if there isn't a way of making Retrofit work with my Deserializer without having to get a raw response and parse it manually when RF should do this for me.

Comment: hmm, seems like you could create a 'TypeAdapterFactory' instead of a deserializer. Check if this can help you  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28736167/5658915

Comment: @JonathanAste that didn't work. Same result :( Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I've got it sussed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @JonathanAste I figured it out.

Instead of a Deserializer, I needed a TypeAdapterFactory implementation.

```
public class ThingTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

       return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

                JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    if (jsonObject.has("things") && jsonObject.get("things").isJsonArray())
                    {
                        jsonElement = jsonObject.get("things");
                    }
                }

                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    if (jsonObject.has("thing") && jsonObject.get("thing").isJsonObject())
                    {
                        jsonElement = jsonObject.get("thing");
                    }
                }

                return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
            }
        }.nullSafe();
    }
}
```

And this allows you to then use

```
@GET("end/of/url/here/{slug}.json") 
Call<List<Thing>> getThings(@Path("slug") String slug);
```

Without issue.